# Can you set a name for a deployed unmanaged package using sfdx CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

So, if I deploy an unmanaged packaged from a VSCode Project, I set a package name as part of the convert command, though there's no option to use this as part of the deploy command:
[image]

```
C:\sfdx\GDPR_Base>sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi_output_dir/ --packagename GDPRTool_Base
Source was successfully converted to Metadata API format and written to the location: C:\sfdx\GDPR_Base\mdapi_output_dir

C:\sfdx\GDPR_Base>sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi_output_dir/ -u EXAMPLEORG -l RunSpecifiedTests -r GDPR_Base_Test,InternalReflectionTest
```

Unfortunately, this name isn't used from the perspective of the org:
[image]

So in the deployment status page, you can only identify your deployment using the ID or the time. Up to now I'd thought that was fine, but had a deployment

Is there any way of getting this name to be recognised (whether through CLI or otherwise), to make it easier for our whole team to see what deployments relate to?

Comment: October 2020 - still no parameter to specify deployment "name" using that method (sfdx force:source:deploy).  A little inconvenient.

Comment: Still not available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you didn't install an unmanaged package - you did a deployment.

If you enable second-generation packaging you could put together either an unmanaged package or (newer feature) an "unlocked package". Then when you install it in the target org it has some traceability to the package it came from.

Or without 2GP, to make it an actual unmanaged package, you'd have to deploy it first to a dev org and then create an unmanaged package from said dev org.